# How to use the api response directly in cp-react-tree-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am using cp-react-tree-table.Unlike in the example, am using the data from api response. but i could not map the data directly from state variable.I dont see sample code for this, everywhere it is given with mock data.

Please find the below code.If i use mock data it works properly, whereas if i assign jsondata with exact same structure,it is not showing anything.

```
 //Get function
var jsondata=await Getdata(id); // api call
    if (jsondata != null) { 
    this.setState({             
        treedata:jsondata,            
        treeValue: TreeState.create(jsondata)            
    });
  }

 //Getdata
const result = await axios({
       method: "get",            
        url: baseUri + `/getvalue/${Id}`

    });   
   return result.data;



    render()
 {  <TreeTable
    value={treeValue}
    onChange={this.handleOnChange}>
    </TreeTable> }
```

Comment: Could you give us code for helping to fix it?

Comment: Added the sample code

Comment: What is `Getdata`? Are you sure it is synchronous?

Comment: I suppose it's not. It's come from api

Comment: Could you share Getdata code?

Comment: Getdata code added. Am getting response from api